# Orckestra C1 upgrading from V5.6 to V6.0 broke MVCFunctions

Tags: model-view-controller, c1-cms, orckestra-cms

Our Orckestra C1 5.6 has been working wonderfully with an implementation of MVCFunctions. After upgrading a test site to V6.0 we noticed the MVC Functions don't seem to be working the same.

An example is a MVCFunction that is handling a form rendering in a page and post back. When I do a view source, the action URL that is resulting from the rendering is very different and the post back fails.

Original MVC in view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Secure", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {  @class = "form-horizontal"}))
```

V5.6 output

```
<form id="loginForm" action="mydomain.com/Login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

V6.0 output

```
<form id="loginForm" action="mydomain.com/Composite/api/Router?action=Login&amp;controller=Secure" class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

When doing the form post in V6 it will just result in a blank page. Can you think of why the action URL was expanded to include a "/Composite/api/Router" as part of the path?

UPDATE: Issues was fixed by the Orckestra team
https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/issues/403

Comment: Remember to update this question with information about your created issue on GitHub and then close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by Orckestra team on GitHub and will be in the next release.

https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/issues/403

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not an answer to solve your problem, but the problem arises from version 6.0 [adding a new WAMP router](https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/blob/455dc2f2090e3d6d2ea0d56eeff1d5d7f73ec9f3/Composite/Core/WebClient/Services/WampRouter/WampRouter.cs#L74) which adds its route to the global RouteTable and affects MVC route resolving.

I would suggest you to open an issue on the [GitHub Issue tracker](https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation).